# Getting error while upgrading from MySQL 8.0.12 to 8.0.32

Tags: mysql

Background:  first, we have upgraded from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 8.0.12 (5.6 --> 5.7 --> 8.0.12) and it was working fine .

Now, we are trying to in-place upgrade from 8.0.12 to 8.0.32 and passed all preliminary checks mentioned in this link ( [Prerequisites](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-prerequisites.html) ).

Upgraded by replacing 8.0.12 binaries with 8.0.32 and tried to start the server. But getting the below error which is related to `datetime` value of one of data dictionary tables.

I have seen many questions which are similar to this error, but those errors are related to user tables. For that reason, I have made the title related to Upgrade process.

```
2023-02-28T13:28:00.305202Z 0 \[System\] \[MY-010116\] \[Server\] C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server       5.6\\bin\\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 13296

2023-02-28T13:28:00.326722Z 1 \[System\] \[MY-013576\] \[InnoDB\] InnoDB initialization has started.

2023-02-28T13:28:01.109930Z 1 \[System\] \[MY-013577\] \[InnoDB\] InnoDB initialization has ended.

2023-02-28T13:28:01.139462Z 1 [System] [MY-011090] [Server] Data dictionary upgrading from version '80012' to  '80023'.

2023-02-28T13:28:07.931896Z 1 \[ERROR\] \[MY-013178\] \[Server\] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'INSERT   INTO st_spatial_reference_systems SELECT \* FROM mysql.st_spatial_reference_systems' failed with error code = 1292, error message = 'Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'last_altered' at row 2'.

2023-02-28T13:28:09.524427Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2023-02-28T13:28:09.524886Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2023-02-28T13:28:11.167707Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server   5.6\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I have tried to access this data dictionary table `mysql.st_spatial_reference_systems` but access is denied.

Is there any way to alter this column default value? Please suggest.

Comment: You need to change the SQL mode to allow zero dates.

Comment: @Barmar How can one change the SQL mode during installation?

Comment: @Barmar - you mean  with ALLOW_INVALID_DATES mode? Tried with that too, but still same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 enforces that dates like '0000-00-00' are not allowed, which is generally a good idea, since those are not valid date values. But zero dates are still in use in some system tables. It seems like an unfortunate oversight in the MySQL development.

`mysql.st_spatial_reference_systems` is a system table that is hidden. You can't access it unless you're running a debug version of MySQL Server.

So to correct this, you'd have to:

1. Uninstall 8.0.32
2. Reinstall a *debug build* of 8.0.12
3. UPDATE values in `mysql.st_spatial_reference_systems` that have zeroes in date columns, setting them to some valid nonzero value.
4. Try the upgrade to 8.0.32 again.

This issue with upgrading was reported as a bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109075 It was closed as "not a bug" because they think it's your responsibility to fix any zero dates before you upgrade — apparently even if they exist in MySQL's on system tables.

The bug comments also suggest that an upgrade from 8.0.13 to 8.0.31 (in the case of the person reporting that bug) was too large, and that they should have upgraded step by step. Are they suggesting that the zero dates would be corrected in some intermediate upgrade version, but it was only a one-time fix? But they do not identify which version's upgrade may have fixed the date. Or maybe the comment is irrelevant.

All said, this is a poor response from the MySQL verification team, and a poor user experience to force such steps to do an upgrade.

---

Another solution might be to install 8.0.32 after changing your option file to set `sql_mode` to permit zero dates. Honestly, I don't know if this would work, because I've never tried to change the `sql_mode` during installation of 8.0.

Even if you get it to work this time, you'd still have to fix the zero dates so you can upgrade in the future. To update the zero dates in the system table manually, it requires you to run a debug build so you can access the hidden tables.

I have no idea if there are more system tables that also contain zero dates.

Comment: [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305697/mysql-8-0-timestamp-current-timestamp-sets-date-to-0000-00-00-000000-was-ok) might (also) be of interest.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, thanks for your quick response.  Agree with you that making debug binaries and update entries in system tables using that debug binaries is hectic and lengthy process. I have also tried with all sql_modes and with empty value, but no luck. Now we have two options 1) make mysql-debug of 8.0.12 and update table values 2) Perform dump and import into new DB with latest version.

Comment: If your database is small enough, the easier path is to dump and restore.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is the one given in the linked "bug": [Bug #109075: upgrade from 8.0.13 to 8.0.31 fails on Data Dictionary initialization](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109075).
Basically, don't do such a big upgrade jump at once. I had the same error message going from 8.0.11 to 8.0.36. I went back to 8.0.11, then upgraded -> 8.0.20 -> 8.0.30 -> 8.0.31 -> 8.0.32 -> 8.0.36. Success! There could probably have been a shorter upgrade path, but it worked for me.